# Bayesian inference MAP question

Tags: bayesian, map-estimation

[Hello I am stuck with this problem and was wondering if someone can solve it for me. Thanks[image: Hello I am stuck with this problem and was wondering if someone can solve it for me. Thanks]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIxz8.png)

Comment: Welcome to this site. Could you indicate where you are stuck as recommended in the [tag:self-study] wiki?